# Protractor - Access to this web page is denied when trying to access automatically - Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, automated-tests

I am learning to use Protractor as the tool to automate web site testing. I am testing the page: https://www.upwork.com/. I am using Google Chrome browser.

The problem is:

1.When protractor goes to: https://www.upwork.com, it works.

2.When I manually(pasting this url to the browser) go to https://www.upwork.com/hire/angularjs-developers/, it works.

3.When protractor goes firstly to: https://www.upwork.com/ and then clicks the text "AngularJS Developers" in BROWSE TOP SKILLS section, it works.

4.But when protractor tries to go directly to https://www.upwork.com/hire/angularjs-developers/, by the method browser.get(url), it doesn't work and this message appears:

"Access to this web page is denied.

Please make sure your browser supports JavaScript and cookies and that you are not blocking them from loading. To learn more about how Upwork uses cookies please review our Cookie Policy."

[image]

I try to make the test independent, so I created 2 classes for tests. One testing HomePage and the second testing the HirePage.
That is why I tried to open browser directly on https://www.upwork.com/hire/angularjs-developers/ to be able to test this site without having to open Home Page and clicking in "AngularJS Developers" text to go to the HirePage.

Cause when the first test won't pass, the second also won't pass and that means that they are dependent. What should I do then and how to resolve this?

Here is the code for HirePage Test:

```
const HirePage = require("../Pages/HirePage");

let hirePage;
const url = browser.params.HirePageURL;
const expectedHeadLine = browser.params.expectedHeadlineOnHirePage;

beforeAll(function () {
    browser.get(url);
    hirePage = new HirePage();
});

describe("Checks Hire page and filering the freelancers after filling 
the data", function () {

    it("Should have correct HeadLine", function () {
        expect(hirePage.headlineUpperText()).toContain(expectedHeadLine);
    });

});
```

Here is my cong.js file:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        // 'chromeOptions': { 'args': ['incognito'] }
        },


    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
        browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10000);
        },

    specs: [
        // './*/HomePageTest-spec.js',
        './*/HirePageTest-spec.js',
    ],
    params: require('./Configuration/configurationFile')
  };
```

I run the test by typing: "protractor conf.js" to the console.

I followed the instructions from Yong in the answers and here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you met same issue when run on Firefox? In genera, we no need to any settings related to enable javascript/cookies.  Try upgrade chromedriver.  Update question tell us which Chrome and Chromedriver you used ?

Comment: I use Google Chrome 64.0.3282.140 and latest chromedriver. On Firefox it works fine.

Comment: I run your url on Chrome 63 and 64 with chromdriver 2.35. Both work fine. Please clarify the version of chromedriver you used.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I check the exact version of my chromedriver?

Comment: I forgot to call you, sorry. @yong

Comment: Show your protractor conf file and the cmd you used to run script

Comment: @yong Ok. So when I ran the test (HirePageTest-spec.js) for the first several times today, it worked. But after several times, that message appeared again. 
I have also another problem which I don't understand. When I uncomment // './*/HomePageTest-spec.js', line because I want protractor to test HomePage firstly and after that -> HirePage, something weird happens. It opens the HomePage and then doesn't do test for that page but opens HirePage immediately. How to make protractor run test firstly for HomePage, and after it finishes the test for HomePage, it then should run tests for HirePage?

Answer (score 0):

Please following steps to check the Cookies and Javascript setting in Chrome instance launched by Automation

1) add a long sleep after open the url, so that you have enought time to stop the running to keep browser instance not closed.

```
beforeAll(function () {
    browser.get('https://www.upwork.com/hire/angularjs-developers/');
    browser.sleep(60*1000);
    hirePage = new HirePage();
});
```

2) run script again, once chrome open and the url opened by automation, back to the cmd window press Ctrl + C, then press Y to end running.

3) open `chrome://settings/content` in new Tab in the unclosed chrome 
   take a screenhost of cookies and javascript settings as below ,
   put the screenshot in your question.

[image]

Until the screenshot we can know the cookies and javascript settings is wrong in your Chrome started by automation